# Look-behind issue with java regex. Look-behind group does not have an obvious maximum length

Tags: java, regex, lookbehind

I need to match `sequence='999'` inside a `<noteinfo>` tag in a xml document using Java RegEx (xml parser is not an option).

Snippet of the xml:

```
<xmltag sequence='11'>
  <noteinfo noteid='1fe' unid='25436AF06906885A8525840B00805DBC' sequence='3'/>
</xmltag>
```

I am using this: `(?<=<noteinfo.*)sequence='[0-9999]'(?=/>)`

I am expecting a match on this: `sequence='3'`

Getting error:  java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Look-behind group does not have an obvious maximum length

I understand the issue is with the .* in the look-behind part. Any alternatives to avoid the error?

Comment: `Any alternatives to avoid the error?` Use a parser.  Seriously it's the only way.

Answer (score 0):

*never use a lookbehind if not absolutely necessary*

You can reduce the length of a lookbehind with the curly braces eg. `{1,255}`.
Your problem is solvable without the use of a lookbehind:
`static final Pattern seqpat = Pattern.compile( "<noteinfo[^>]+(?<seq>sequence\\s*=\\s*'[\\d]*')", Pattern.MULTILINE );`

read through the file with:

```
Matcher m = seqpat.matcher( s );
while( m.find() )
  System.err.println( m.group( "seq" ) );
```

`Pattern.MULTILINE` is necessary in the case a noteinfo-line is wrapped
`seqpat` finds (not matches!) any line starting with `<noteinfo` and ending with `>`
the requested sequence is captured in `group( "seq" )`
perhaps You have to deal with spaces or newlines between `sequence`, `=` and the sequence-id `'3'` — therefore: `\\s*=\\s*`

*the above Pattern finds each sequence-id (even an empy one)*
to find only the `'999'` sequence-id, take this Pattern:
`Pattern.compile( "<noteinfo[^>]+(?<seq>sequence\\s*=\\s*'999')", Pattern.MULTILINE );`

Answer (score -1):

My guess is that you might want to design an expression similar to:

```
(?=<noteinfo).*(sequence='[0-9]'|sequence='[1-9][0-9]{0,3}')
```

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/JxqZSY/1/)

#### Test

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

final String regex = "(?=<noteinfo).*(sequence='[0-9]'|sequence='[1-9][0-9]{0,3}')";
final String string = "<xmltag sequence='11'>\n"
     + "  <noteinfo noteid='1fe' unid='25436AF06906885A8525840B00805DBC' sequence='3'/>\n"
     + "</xmltag>\n"
     + "<xmltag sequence='11'>\n"
     + "  <noteinfo noteid='1fe' unid='25436AF06906885A8525840B00805DBC' sequence='9999'/>\n"
     + "</xmltag>\n"
     + "<xmltag sequence='11'>\n"
     + "  <noteinfo noteid='1fe' unid='25436AF06906885A8525840B00805DBC' sequence='10000'/>\n"
     + "</xmltag>\n"
     + "<xmltag sequence='11'>\n"
     + "  <noteinfo noteid='1fe' unid='25436AF06906885A8525840B00805DBC' sequence='-1'/>\n"
     + "</xmltag>";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
    for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
    }
}
```